# Ubuntu 16.04 booting to BusyBox prompt when I update my kernel

Tags: boot, kernel

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 4.10.0-42-generic on Intel Compute Sticks, which exhibit the [c-state bug](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=109051), which is apparently fixed after kernel 4.11.

I've attempted to install 4.15.0-42-generic with the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-image-4.15.0-42-generic linux-headers-4.15.0-42-generic linux-hwe-tools-4.15.0-42 fdutils
```

This gave me warnings about 3 missing drivers. I found these and downloaded them:

```
cd /lib/firmware/i915`
sudo wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/i915/kbl_huc_ver02_00_1810.bin
sudo wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/i915/bxt_huc_ver01_07_1398.bin
sudo wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/i915/skl_huc_ver01_07_1398.bin
```

I then ran the following:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
sudo update-grub
```

The missing driver warnings are now gone. However, whenever I reboot into the new 4.15.0-42 kernel I get dropped to a BusyBox terminal with an (initramfs) prompt.

I have the 4.15.0-42-generic kernel running on the same devices, though I didn't install it manually; so I'm sure it's just something I'm doing wrong.

I've also attempted the same process with 4.13 and had the same outcome.

Any light that could be shed on this would be greatly appreciated. If there is more info I can provide please let me know.

Comment: Two suggestions... `fsck -f` your Ubuntu partition, and redo your `update-initramfs` using `-c -k 4.15.0-42-generic`. Then reboot. Report back to @heynnema

Comment: Thanks for the response @heynnema, much appreciated. Unfortunately these units in question are in a live production environment, so it may take me a couple of days to get back to you with results on a reproducible offline unit.

Comment: Please do keep me posted.

Comment: Apologies for the late update @heynnema, I believe the issue was that I was installing the new kernels but not running apt-get dist-upgrade to include package upgrades. I'm yet to confirm this on the actual devices in question; but have found this to work on subsequent devices.